# Has the percent of unplanned pregnancies in France increased since the legalization of contraception in 1967?

Tags: demographics, france

Has the percent of unintended pregnancies (relatively to all pregnancies) risen since legal contraception was first introduced in France in 1967. Where can I find a graph like this: y-axis is the percentage and x-axis being years from 1967 to 2023? Is there data before 1967 to compare?